# Variables not updating in C

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the full code. The printf shows that the max and min are changing but the random number doesnt reflect this. it still exceeds the boundries. Im new to C and have only used Java until now. I have a feeling pointers have something to do with this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
  //initalised the max and min values for the random number
  int max = 100;
  int min = 1;
  int randomNumber;
  int endGame = 0; //set to 0 as game has not been won yet

  //asking your for their number which the program will guess
  char input[3];
  printf("Please enter a number between 1-100 and I will try to guess it: ");
  scanf(" %c \n", input);

  srand(time(NULL));

  while(endGame == 0){
    //generates random number and prints it. asks for users input
    randomNumber = (rand()%max)+min;

    printf("My guess is: %d \n", randomNumber);
    printf("Max: %d  \n", max);
    printf("Min: %d  \n", min);
    //printf("Press 'l' if your number is lower or 'h' if your number is higher$
    char c;
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    if(c == 'l'){
      max = randomNumber;
    }
    if(c == 'h'){
      min = randomNumber;
    }
    if(c == 'c'){
      endGame = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that code even compile? I don't see a main function? Also, **INDENT** your code properly, it really helps when you need to understand the code.

Comment: To get a random number between max and min, it should be `(rand() % (max-min)) + min`

Comment: `char input[3];` --> `char input[4], c;` ... `scanf("%3s%c", input, &c);` .. then validation of `input` and `c`.

Comment: You don't need to call `srand()` every time in the loop, just call it once at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Why do you use a `char` array for a number? Why does the program even need to ask for the number, it never uses that variable?

Comment: @neve_exe if you edit your post with you full code, with main() maybe I can provide you a better solution.

Comment: The one part of the program I don't see any problem with is the `if` statements, although I would use `else if` since they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: If the `printf()` statements say that the variables update, why do you think they're not updating? Maybe the real problem is your incorrect code for picking a random number.

Comment: @Barmar `(max-min)` --> `(max-min+1)`

Comment: You also need to set  `min` to `randomNumber+1`. Otherwise it will be allowed to pick the same number.

Answer (score -1):

scanf() takes a format specifier and a pointer to a character as an argument. You can do what you did, but i would declare char * c instead of char c and pass that directly to the call to scanf, like this:

```
char * c = malloc (sizeof (char));
scanf (" %c", c);
```

Then in your if statements you will need to dereference your pointer to compare the value of c to your relevant constants. The **dereference operator, '*'** is used to do this. For example:

```
if (*c == 'l') {
  min = randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, he did pass the pointer using the reference operator. I Should have called malloc as well.